# What does import {} from '.' do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

I was looking at [some source code of a library](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/69ecc75797469357be054215ebeeae443121559d/packages/react-jss/src/JssProvider.test.js#L10) and I saw this import

```
import {SheetsRegistry, JssProvider, withStyles} from '.'
```

What does this do? How does it import `from '.'` ?

Comment: It imports those declarations from `index.js` in the same directory.

Comment: Imports the declarations from `index.ts` in the same folder.

Comment: @Oliver Or `index.d.ts`

Comment: Import from the `index.js` file at the same level as your current file. The equivalent of `./index`

Comment: Note that this isn't defined by JavaScript, it's defined by the environment in which the import is being processed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is this some extra config or it's normal in a react environment? Before sawing that, I did `import {} from './index'` but not sure if only `.` will work

Comment: @Vencovsky - It's just that the meaning of module specifiers is determined by the host environment, not by the language spec. Bundlers, Node.js, and browsers all have their own semantics for module specifiers (though -- because people aren't stupid -- there's a lot of overlap :-) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you shared imports those declarations from [index.js](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss/blob/69ecc75797469357be054215ebeeae443121559d/packages/react-jss/src/index.js) in the same directory.

*index.js:*

```
// @flow
import withStyles from './withStyles'

export {ThemeProvider, withTheme, createTheming, useTheme} from 'theming'
export {default as createUseStyles} from './createUseStyles'
export {default as JssProvider} from './JssProvider'
export {default as jss} from './jss'
export {SheetsRegistry, createGenerateId} from 'jss'
export {default as JssContext} from './JssContext'
export {default as styled} from './styled'
export {default as jsx, create as createJsx} from './jsx'
export {withStyles}

// Kept for backwards compatibility.
export default withStyles
```

In this example, `index.js` is being used to re-export some of the declarations within the `src` directory. This pattern makes it easier to move the declarations around without having to rewrite many imports.

Answer (score 0):

******The difference between named exports and default exports.******

**1-named exports**

export function, constant, variable...etc in **Constant.js**

```
export const CREATE = 'CREATE';
export const DELETE = 'DELETE';
```

import like this in **index.js**

```
import {CREATE,DELETE} from './Constants';
```

**2-default exports**

export it in **Constant.js**

```
const update = ()=> 'UPDATE'
export default update();
```

and import like this in index.js

```
import UPDATE from './Constants';
```

[image: multiple types]